# Mac OS - Tkinter: Dynamically change style of built in close button

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

## Hello Guys

### Problem:

I have a `tkinter` app where you are able to save text into a text document. When you wrote something that is not already saved you should see a little dot in the red closing button like in the image from Word (I am on Mac OS Big Sur). Also when you click on that button this message box appears:

[image]

[image]

### My Try:

I currently solved it that way so when the user clicks on the exit button a `tkinter` message box appears. Like this.

```
    def task_exit(self,e=None):
        if self.root.title()[(-1)] != '*' or askyesno('Close Project',
                                                      'There are unsaved changes',default="no"):
            self.root.destroy()
            return
```

This code gives me (Ignore that it is not the same text):

[image]

### Question

Is there any possible way of doing this in the recent `tkinter` versions or may this be a not yet added feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally figured out how to do it. Well at least the first part.
When you want the little dot in the top left corner you just can put this line at the right place.

`root.wm_attributes("-modified", 0)`

When I find a solution to the second part, I will edit my answer.